# React Router - Rendering <Redirect> instead of a child list component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following code:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import QPContent from '../QPContent';

class AnswerContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      redirect: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { redirect } = this.state;
    if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect push to={'/question/'+this.props.qID}/>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="qp-answer-container">
        ....
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownprops) => ({
....
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
....
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AnswerContainer);`
```

I have an array of `AnswerContainer` components in a parent component. I am currently in the route `/question/qId`. I am trying to refresh the page on setting `redirect: true`. So when I use `setState()` and change the state of only one component in the list to `redirect: true`, the parent component doesn't re-render. Instead, the child component disappears. Why is this happening and how to trigger re-render of the whole page on `<Redirect/>` ?

Note: I'm calling `setState()` inside an action `dispatch`

Comment: I think `const { redirect } = this.state;` should be `const { redirect } = this.state.redirect;`

Comment: @Dane where do you are calling the `setState()` method ?, remember that if `AnswerContainer` is the child component his `state` is not the same that the parent, so if you change the state in the parent component you need to pass the state to the `AnswerContainer` or the redirect flag as a prop from the parent to the children

Comment: @JoxieMedina sorry I forgot to include the `setState()` call. I call it inside a `dispatch` by passing `this` as context

Comment: @SKJajoriya No I think it works... in ES6 syntax. See **Object Destructuring** here: [MDN - Destructuring Assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to re-render the whole page, just use [`window.location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).

The idea of `<Redirect />` component is to update the current url, not to re-render components. Of course they usually do re-render since most commonly you display something else when the url changes. But the job of react is to re-render as little as possible.

Comment: So what happens when just one of the components in a list of components render `<Redirect/>` ?

Comment: A whole chain of events happen. When `Redirect` component is rendered, it pushes new location state to `history`, which updates the current URL.

In turn, when the URL changes, other components (like `Route`) react to that — and they render something or unmount something accordingly.

Comment: But if it's redirecting to the same URL, the component does not mount and unmount, right ?